# How to get all feeds of my fanpage in facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How can I get all feeds of my fan page?
I am using graph api using this url
https://graph.facebook.com/mypagename/feed?until=today&access_token=$access_token

```
$status_data= file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/mypagename/feed?until=today&access_token=$access_token");
$status = json_decode($status_data,true);
```

access_token is valid. Everything works fine. I have take permission also.(read_stream)
but it only return 50 to 52 posts.

I want to return all posts.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just calling:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/mypagename/feed?access_token=$access_token
```

The API should return a fixed default set (most recent 25 posts).  However, it should also return a `paging` object which lets you access the next 25:

```
 "paging": {
"previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/mypagename/feed?format=json&limit=25&since=1317858935", 
"next": "https://graph.facebook.com/mypagename/feed?format=json&limit=25&until=1315842409"
```

Your code can parse the paging links automatically until the end to retrieve all posts.